# WebGL FPS camera movement along the local axis instead of the world axis with glMatrix.js

Tags: camera, rotation, webgl, translation

I'm trying to make a FPS camera in WebGL.
When I move the camera from the initial position and then rotate, the camera moves along the start position instead of the new position.
The translation and rotation are made with glMatrix.js library.

I have the variables:

```
var rotateY = 0;  // For rotating along the Y axis
var fronBackMovement = 0;   // Front and back movement
var sideMovement  = 0;  // Movement from side to side
```

Keyboard events:

```
// Movement
if( key.w == true ){
    fronBackMovement += 5;
}
if( key.a == true ){
    sideMovement += 5;
}
if( key.s == true ){
    fronBackMovement -= 5;
}
if( key.d == true ){
    sideMovement -= 5;
}
```

Mouse movement:

```
// Rotation
if( mouse.movementX != 0 ){
    rotateY += mouse.movementX;  // mouse.movementX is screen movement of the cursor
}
```

Translation and rotation:

```
camera.matrix = mat4.fromTranslation( mat4.create() ,vec3.fromValues(sideMovement,0,fronBackMovement) )
camera.matrix = mat4.rotateY(camera.matrix,camera.matrix,rotateY )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera generally looks down the -Z axis so to move forward you just add the camera's Z axis to your position. If you don't want to move vertically then zero out the Y component and normalize. Finally multiply by your desired speed.

The camera's x-axis contains the side movement direction so you can do the same for that.

```
const cameraPosition = vec3.create();
const tempForwardDirection = vec3.create();
const tempSideDirection = vec3.create();
...


tempForwardDirection[0] = camera.matrix[8];
tempForwardDirection[1] = 0;  // camera.matrix[9];
tempForwardDirection[2] = camera.matrix[10];
vec3.normalize(tempForwardDirection, tempForwardDirection)

tempSideDirection[0] = camera.matrix[0];
tempSideDirection[1] = camera.matrix[1];
tempSideDirection[2] = camera.matrix[2];

vec3.scaleAndAdd(
    cameraPosition,
    cameraPosition,
    tempForwardDirection, 
    -fronBackMovement);
vec3.scaleAndAdd(
    cameraPosition,
    cameraPosition,
    tempSideDirection,
    sideMovement)

camera.matrix = mat4.fromTranslation(camera.matrix, cameraPosition);
camera.matrix = mat4.rotateY(camera.matrix,camera.matrix,rotateY);
```

```js
let rotateY = 0;  // For rotating along the Y axis
let fronBackMovement = 0;   // Front and back movement
let sideMovement  = 0;  // Movement from side to side

const cameraPosition = vec3.create();
const tempForwardDirection = vec3.create();
const tempSideDirection = vec3.create();

const camera = {
  matrix: mat4.create(),
};
const mouse = {
  movementX: 0,
};

const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
const vs = `
uniform mat4 u_worldViewProjection;
uniform mat4 u_worldInverseTranspose;

attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec3 normal;

varying vec3 v_normal;

void main() {
  gl_Position = u_worldViewProjection * position;
  v_normal = (u_worldInverseTranspose * vec4(normal, 0)).xyz;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec3 v_normal;
uniform vec3 u_lightDir;
uniform vec4 u_color;

void main() {
  vec3 norm = normalize(v_normal);
  float light = dot(u_lightDir, norm) * .5 + .5;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(u_color.rgb * light, u_color.a);
}
`;

const progInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
const bufferInfo = twgl.primitives.createCubeBufferInfo(gl, 1);

const projection = mat4.create();
const view = mat4.create();
const viewProjection = mat4.create();
const world = mat4.create();
const worldViewProjection = mat4.create();
const worldInverse = mat4.create();
const worldInverseTranspose = mat4.create();

const fov = degToRad(90);
const zNear = 0.1;
const zFar = 100;

const lightDir = vec3.normalize(vec3.create(), [1, 2, 3]);

const key = {};

let px = 0;
let py = 0;
let pz = 0;
let elev = 0;
let ang = 0;
let roll = 0;
const speed = 1;
const turnSpeed = 90;

let then = 0;
function render(now) {
  now *= 0.001;  // seconds;
  const deltaTime = now - then;
  then = now;
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
  
  gl.useProgram(progInfo.program);
  
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  mat4.perspective(projection, fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);

  fronBackMovement = 0;
  sideMovement = 0;
  
  if( key.w == true ){
      fronBackMovement = 5 * deltaTime;
  }
  if( key.a == true ){
      sideMovement = -5 * deltaTime;
  }
  if( key.s == true ){
      fronBackMovement = -5 * deltaTime;
  }
  if( key.d == true ){
      sideMovement = 5 * deltaTime;
  }

  // Rotation
  if( mouse.movementX != 0 ){
      rotateY += mouse.movementX / 200;  // mouse.movementX is screen movement of the cursor
      mouse.movementX = 0;
  }

  tempForwardDirection[0] = camera.matrix[8];
  tempForwardDirection[1] = 0;  // camera.matrix[9];
  tempForwardDirection[2] = camera.matrix[10];
  vec3.normalize(tempForwardDirection, tempForwardDirection)

  tempSideDirection[0] = camera.matrix[0];
  tempSideDirection[1] = camera.matrix[1];
  tempSideDirection[2] = camera.matrix[2];

  vec3.scaleAndAdd(
      cameraPosition,
      cameraPosition,
      tempForwardDirection, 
      -fronBackMovement);
  vec3.scaleAndAdd(
      cameraPosition,
      cameraPosition,
      tempSideDirection,
      sideMovement)

  camera.matrix = mat4.fromTranslation(camera.matrix, cameraPosition);
  camera.matrix = mat4.rotateY(camera.matrix,camera.matrix,rotateY);


  mat4.invert(view, camera.matrix);

  mat4.multiply(viewProjection, projection, view);
  
  for (let z = -1; z <= 1; ++z) {
    for (let y = -1; y <= 1; ++y) {
      for (let x = -1; x <= 1; ++x) {
        if (x === 0 && y === 0 && z === 0) {
          continue;
        }
        
        mat4.identity(world);
        mat4.translate(world, world, [x * 3, y * 3, z * 3]);
        
        mat4.multiply(worldViewProjection, viewProjection, world);
        mat4.invert(worldInverse, world);
        mat4.transpose(worldInverseTranspose, worldInverse);
        
        twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, progInfo, bufferInfo);
        twgl.setUniforms(progInfo, {
          u_worldViewProjection: worldViewProjection,
          u_worldInverseTranspose: worldInverseTranspose,
          u_color: [(x + 2) / 3, (y + 2) / 3, (z + 2) / 3, 1],
          u_lightDir: lightDir,
        });
        twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);
      }
    }
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  key[e.key] = true;
  e.preventDefault();
});
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  key[e.key] = false;
  e.preventDefault();
});
window.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  mouse.movementX = e.movementX;
});


function degToRad(d) {
  return d * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
pre { position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gl-matrix/2.8.1/gl-matrix-min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
<pre>
A = left
D = right
W = forward
S = down
</pre>
```

---

[image]

Comment: For some reason I still get the same camera movement

Comment: By the sound of it OP has the same confusion as myself - if the camera doesn't move, but instead we move the world around the camera, shouldn't "forward" always be in the direction of the original z-axis, `[0,0,1]`? (which seems reasonable since the camera hasn't moved). This seems half true. We do move in the direction of the z-axis, but it isn't `[0,0,1]`. In practice I see that treating “forward” as a z-axis of `[0,0,1]` gives incorrect results. Yet I can’t quite square this with the idea that “the camera doesn’t move” - I don’t understand why forward isn’t always down a z-axis of `[0,0,1]`

Comment: I see you do a lot of matrix setup within the render function. Is the reason you initialise movement values to 0 (and reset mouse `movementX` to 0 after use) because otherwise the render function would spin out of control from conitually applying non-zero movements? Is it feasible to set the camera matrix outside the render loop (say in event handlers) and therefore sidestep having to be cautious about setting values to 0?